# Media queries working in FF and CH but not IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am trying to figure out why my media queries are working in Firefox and Chrome but not Internet Explorer 11.

Page here: http://skeeterz71.com/auto/dealers.html

The top form, the photos and information should be centering on the page at these: If anybody has time to look, I would appreciate it.

```
@media (max-width: 775px){
    .bold-product-headline{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .product-image-left{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .dealer-headline{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .dealer-location{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .dealer-phone{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .dealer-information{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .search-by-city{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .search-by-city-select{
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

***Note:** I am using Bootstrap, but do not know of a bs class that will center in tablet and phone view only.*

Comment: you are running on which version of ie ?

Comment: @KrunalPanchal : IE11...OP mentioned that in question :)

Comment: Try `@media screen and (max-width: 775px) { ... }`

Comment: Please, could you test the web in other IE versions (9, 10). This help us to determine if it's a general browser issue or the problem are with that specific version... btw media queries are working fine (for me) in IE9.

Comment: A screenshot could help too. I see the same thing pretty much in Chrome and IE11

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things i can suggest because of which it won't be working :

- add where media query should work, eg `screen`

  `@media only screen and (max-width : 775px) {}`
- check that **compatibility mode is off** or not...*most of the times this is the problem*
- missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` from your document page

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys: Nevermind. Didn't have a closing tag on one of the queries. I went over the css so many times trying to find the issue and didn't see it until about the 10th time. Probably should call it a day.

I noticed in the inspect element in ie it didn't even see the media query at all. That clued me in and should have been my first thing I should of done....

FF and chrome saw the media query and ie didn't. Strange, but ie was right in this case. FF and chrome were giving me to much slack:)